# firebase stopped responding and lost all data without any error or issue

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I Lost All the data from My Firebase realtime database. This is working properly last day. Suddenly This stopped working and lost all My Users Data.
Even now I can't add New Data also. I did nothing in the last 30+ days in the firebase or app. this is working properly in the last day.
can anybody has the same problem with firebase? if yes then how you got a solution for this?
And I can't even change the rules of firebase also. shows me try again dialog only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Firebase Engineer here*

It looks like there is a network problem at one or more ISPs that prevents users on those networks for accessing the database. The databases itself and users on other networks are not affected.

We're investigating further, but in the meantime you should be able to work around the problem by using another network/provider.

We'll continue to provide status update here and on https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Realtime%20Database/20008

---

Update: at the moment this problem is confirmed for users on Reliance Jio networks.

Update: We see fewer reports of this problem, but will continue to monitor and provide updates.

Update: The issue on the Firebase dashboard has been closed, as the number of reports approached zero. If you're still seeing the issue, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) so they can track. I'd also recommend reaching out to the affected providers directly, if you have a way to do so.

Comment: I noticed one weird thing that when I am using the internet from my phone and accessing DB, it is working but when I connect my other phone with wifi from the first phone, it's not working.
Hope it might help!

Comment: This issue is not fixed yet, I am using Vodafone/Idea network and the APP is not able to connect to  RealtimeDatabase.

Comment: Still having the same issue multiple times on Vodafone network

Comment: Hey @Dev. Sorry to hear so. Did you [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting yet? If the problem recurred, they might be able to reach out to the provider again.