# my realtime firebase project database not open or work

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

Today I shocked that all my realtime firebase database not exist even not enable to create a new database
when i press rules tab i received failure message[image: Satuation of my firebase database]

Comment: *firebaser here* It looks like you're affecting by the same problem reported here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63723299. I'll follow up there when there's more information/

Answer (score 1):

1. Check the JavaScript console for error.
2. Try in a different browser, or disable all extensions (like ad-blockers).
3. If the problem remains, there's not much any of us can do here. In that case, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting